# Loading very large RDF triples into iGraph -> Fast vertices lookup?

Tags: python, rdf, igraph, redland

I need to load a subset of the DBPedia graph into iGraph in order to compute some graph statistics (such as node centrality, ...). I load DBPedia triples using the Redlands libRDF python library. Each node is associated with an URI (unique identifier).

I have some trouble loading the graph into iGraph. This is what I do:

1) Read a triple line (subject, predicate, object)

2) Use the following algorithm to get or create a vertex (with attribute)

```
def add_or_find_vertex (self, g, uri):
    try:
        return g.vs.find(name=uri)
    except (KeyError, ValueError):
        g.add_vertex(name=uri)
        return g.vs.find(name=uri)

subjVertex = self.add_or_find_vertex(self.g, subject)
objVertex = self.add_or_find_vertex(self.g, object)
self.g.add_edge(subjVertex, objVertex, uri=predicate)
```

The problem is that my script is very slow and I need to load 25M triples. Each node is unique but is found several time in the triple file. I thus need to perform a lookup before creating the edge. Can you tell me if the "find" method is using an index for lookups (Hashtable, ...)? What is the complexity of vertex lookups ? How would you do ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Load all edges in a list and create the graph with a single call.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GaborCsardi. Indeed, the bottleneck was the `add_edge()` call, which I was calling for every relation one at a time.  Instead, we created a list of edges into a Python List and flushed that list at the end with `add_edges(list)`.  Now, it is super fast!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already answered [here](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/615). For sake of completeness, I'm copying my answer here as well:

> Vertex lookups are usually O(|V|) since vertex attributes are not indexed by default - *except* the `name` vertex attribute, which is indexed. However `g.vs.find` is using this index only if you do this: `g.vs.find(url)` but not if you do this: `g.vs.find(name=url)`. This is sort of a bug as the index could be used in both cases. Also see [yesterday's thread](http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2014-05/msg00069.html) from the mailing list.
>
> However, note that igraph's data structures are optimized for static graphs, so `g.add_vertex` (and I presume you also use `g.add_edge`) could also be a bottleneck. Internally, igraph uses an indexed edge list to store the graph and the index has to be re-built every time you mutate the graph, so it is much more efficient to do vertex and edge additions in batches where possible.
>
> Since you already seem to have an iterator that yields the edges of your graph in `(subject, predicate, object)` form, maybe it's easier to use `Graph.DictList` to construct the graph at once because it also takes care of storing the vertex IDs in the `name` attribute, adding edges in batches where it makes sense, and also adding the `predicate` attribute from your triplets:
>
> ```
> >>> g = Graph.DictList(vertices=None, edges=({"source": subject,
> ...         "target": object, "predicate": predicate}
> ...         for subject, predicate, object in your_iterator))
> ```
>
> `Graph.DictList` processes 100000 pre-generated random triplets in 1.63 seconds on my machine so I guess that improves things a little bit.

Comment: Awesome, I understand better how the iGraph data structure is working now.  Maybe, it would be worth to add a comment in the documentation to let potential users know what are the complexity of such operations.